# Issue trying to run ReduxSimple library on Uno Platform Wasm

Tags: c#, webassembly, uno-platform

someone could help me with this issue:

```
VM59:1 fail: Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcher[0]
      Dispatcher unhandled exception
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Arg_PlatformNotSupported
   at System.Threading.Thread.Start(Object parameter) in D:\a\Uno.DotnetRuntime.WebAssembly\Uno.DotnetRuntime.WebAssembly\runtime\src\mono\System.Private.CoreLib\src\System\Threading\Thread.Browser.Mono.cs:line 17
   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.ConcurrencyAbstractionLayerImpl.StartThread(Action`1 action, Object state) in /_/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Concurrency/ConcurrencyAbstractionLayerImpl.cs:line 71
   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.DefaultScheduler.LongRunning.LongScheduledWorkItem`1[[System.Reactive.ObserveOnObserverLongRunning`1[[ReduxSimple.ActionDispatchedWithOrigin, ReduxSimple, Version=3.6.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Reactive, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94bc3704cddfc263]]..ctor(ObserveOnObserverLongRunning`1 state, Action`2 action) in /_/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Concurrency/DefaultScheduler.cs:line 185
   at System.Reactive.Concurrency.DefaultScheduler.LongRunning.ScheduleLongRunning[ObserveOnObserverLongRunning`1](ObserveOnObserverLongRunning`1 state, Action`2 action) in /_/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Concurrency/DefaultScheduler.cs:line 204
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Rx` method you're using is trying to start a thread, which is not supported on WebAssembly. WebAssembly is currently [single-threaded](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/api-differences.html#webassembly-is-single-threaded) only. You'll need to rewrite your code so that it's not trying to use a background thread. Using [platform-specific code](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/platform-specific-csharp.html) may be of interest.

You can track the support for multi-threading in WebAssembly as it relates to Uno Platform in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/2302).